# How can I convert string like '3x a;2x b' to string 'a a a b b' in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns is column with categories. Format of rows in that column is like '3x category1;4x category2; an so on'. For each of such rows I want to get string where I have *category* repeated *x* times.

Here is example of what I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'categories': ['3x bank;6x call center', '3x silent call;4x another'],
                         'phone_number': [79294347795, 79242935107]})
df

      |                categories | phone_number
  ----|---------------------------|--------------    
    0 |   3x bank;2x call center  | 79294347795
  ----|---------------------------|--------------
    1 | 2x silent call;2x another | 79242935107
```

And here is what I want to get

```
      |                              categories |  phone_number
  ----|-----------------------------------------|---------------
    0 |  bank bank bank call center call center |  79294347795
  ----|-----------------------------------------|---------------
    1 | silent call silent call another another |  79242935107
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your data that be copied and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Please provide a [mre] with your question.

Comment: Should be straightforward.  Split on `;`.  Split each substring on space.  If there are exactly two sub-substrings, and the first sub-substring matches the regex `\dx`, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, do you want something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['3x a', '4x b', '5x e']})

df1 = df['category'].str.extract('(?P<num>\d)x (?P<cat>\w+)')
df1['cat'].repeat(df1['num'])
```

Output:

```
0    a
0    a
0    a
1    b
1    b
1    b
1    b
2    e
2    e
2    e
2    e
2    e
Name: cat, dtype: object
```